# People tracking with fisheye camera

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working with some fisheye cameras mounted on the ceiling. What I want to do it them is to track people, get their position in the ground plane and an estimate on their speed. I've never worked with this kind of cameras before, does anyone have any idea on how to tackle this issue?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193707/people-tracking-with-fisheye-camera/) by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For working with the cameras, your first step will be to [calibrate](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) the camera, and obtain the rectified image stream using [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc).

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) on 2014-09-29**:
Thank you! I'll check that